# How can I prevent programs from closing on my Azure virtual machine while I'm not using it?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, sleep, remote-access, azure

If I disconnect from an Azure virtual Windows machine for several hours, the programs get closed by the time I open it again, and then not all of them re-open automatically. How can I stop this from happenning?

The machine isn't set to shut down automatically.

To answer Pimp Juice IT's questions, I'm running Windows 10 Pro, version 1809, OS build 17763.1098. The processor is Intel Xeon E5-2673 v4 @ 2.30GHz. RAM is 7GiB. The disk space available is 61.5GiB (out of 159GiB).
It's on the High Performance power plan, and the screen is set to never turn off. When I leave the machine for several hours, *all* the programs close, so it's not program specific. I use Chrome, [Stata](https://www.stata.com), Windows Explorer, WhatsApp Desktop and Sumatra PDF reader.

Note that I think this is a problem specific to the Azure virtual machine settings, not the operating system.

Comment: Are these VMs in Azure connected to a domain or using a custom image?  Windows systems in Azure by default don't typically have a session timeout set but that can easily be overwritten by domain policy or a local policy set by employers.

Comment: @KenWMSFT I only need one machine for my own personal use, so I'm not using a domain.

Comment: I created this machine myself.

Comment: Ahorn - I think you need to provide more detail to get help here with accuracy. You are running Windows 10 Home Edition, Enterprise, or what? How much RAM, how many CPU, what programs in particular are you running? How much disk space on the drive partitions from the Windows 10 is available, not running low anywhere, right? How are the power settings from the OS configured, you have hibernate, sleep, etc. disabled? Any research or narrowing this down yourself that may be helpful to those that read which may be able to help you to ensure accurate and up to date detail is disclosed.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I've updated my question with answers to your questions.